# converting a 6 byte slice to to little endian

Tags: go

I want to convert a 6 byte slice to little Endian encoding.

I am parsing an array using byte slices and converting them to little Endian using The Read function of binary package.  But When I parse a 6 byte slice e.g. {05,00,00,00,00,00}  it returns zero  (hex notation) with data interface being uint64. Is there any way to do this using the above function and not hardcoding it. Note that if I pad the residual two bytes zeros I get the result but somehow the my parser misses the following two bytes of the array.

Thanks for your help/suggestions.

Comment: Show code. Your question is completely un-understandable. E.g. `{05,00,00,00,00,00}` is _not_ a byte slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode it by hand. It's trivial:

```
b := []byte{5,0,0,0,0,0,0}
i := uint64(b[0]) |
     uint64(b[1]) << 8 |
     uint64(b[2]) << 16 |
     uint64(b[3]) << 24 |
     uint64(b[4]) << 32 |
     uint64(b[5]) << 40
```

Comment: exactly but I already knew that, 6 bytes is because of an attribute of a Microsoft data structure. Who would use 6 bytes but it turns out that MS does

Comment: Erm.. so why don't you just add the two extra bytes?  There's nothing wrong with using 6 bytes to encode an integer, or with any other size, for that matter.

Comment: You are right about the encoding. I tried padding with zeros but as I mentioned in my question in my implementation the following two bytes of the array were missed.

Comment: It's not clear what you don't know then. You accepted an answer that makes no sense.